# Prepared statements functions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so i learning prepared statements in php because i hear they are a lot safer that mysql

So now im just getting the hand of functions. I have made a function which connects to the mysql db and have it in a different folder that the page i want to use it on. So i want all my main functions in 1 file then i want to call them from the file on the pages i need them on.  But now php does not like it.

Here is my functions.php page

```
function mysqlconnect(){

$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306; // This is the default port for MySQL
$database = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';

// Construct the DSN, or "Data Source Name".  Really, it's just a fancy name
// for a string that says what type of server we're connecting to, and how
// to connect to it.  As long as the above is filled out, this line is all
// you need :)
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";

// Connect!
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
}
```

And here is my test page just testing calling the function.

```
include 'functions/functions.php';

mysqlconnect();

$_POST['fish'] = "shadow" ;

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$statement->execute(array($_POST['fish']));

while ($result = $statement->fetchObject()) {
    echo $result->username;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Notice i include the file and call the function but im getting:

Notice: Undefined variable: db 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-objec

If i put the connect in the same php file has it everything works fine. But of course id like all the function in the same file and just call them when ever i need them.  What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Why are you manually setting the `$_POST` superglobal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$db` is defined inside a function, so it cannot become global. It's scope ends when the function ends.

You should define `$db` *outisde* your function.

A not-so-elegant solution:

```
function mysqlconnect(){
  global $db; 
  $host = 'localhost';
  // etc.etc.
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
}
```

Please take note that using `global`, expecially in this context, is a really bad practice (it undermines code cleanliness, code reusability, and can lead to several other problems).

A more elegant solution (like the other user says):

```
function mysqlconnect(){

  $host = 'localhost';
  // etc.etc.
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  return $db;
}
```

And then in your test page:

```
$db = mysqlconnect();
```

This is useful as you can use any variable name: makes your code more reusable in other scenarios.

```
$donaldduck = mysqlconnect();
```

would be ok too.

Comment: I would just scratch the first "solution".

Comment: @Cranio I told you you [should have removed it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762591/php-simple-login-script-white-page)...

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I'm open to criticism, but I'd expect comments to be more polite and constructive. If I am wrong and the solution doesn't work, I'll remove it. As for now I can't see a reason. Please be more constructive in your comments, you're talking with a user willing to help and ready to take criticism and you are been read by less expert users who wish to know why you complain about what I've written. Thank you.

Comment: I add that I surely may have overlooked something, I followed your links but it's not clear if the "global" trick is COMPLETELY not working or just a very bad practice (and I have clearly stated that I'd prefer the second way).

Comment: @Cranio I have been polite AFAIK. It's not that it is not working it is the fact that it is really really bad practice. The reason I don't like it in an answer is the fact that people are going to use it (even though you have stated it is not the best option). Hence the reason I linked to the other question of OP where he indeed used it. Again my comment was in **no** way meant to be rude or anything or to talk down to you. And you showed in your answer that you know `global`s are bad, that's why I said just remove it al together. :-)

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa What I meant is that an explanation in the answer like now is way more useful for me and the other readers to learn things. I too didn't mean to be rude at all; I thank you for taking the patience this time and yes, I am convinced to stress that it's a bad practice by editing the article. (But not removing the option, I think globals are still an option and functioning code, even if horrible).

Answer (score 0):

`$db` is inside a function and cannot be used outside.  Look into [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  You can either declare `$db` as a global variable, or return `$db` from the function and then set `$db=mysqlconnect()`.  There are dozens of other ways to do it, but as you have it, it can't be done.

Side note: I would personally do this:

```
function mysqlconnect(){
    /* your code here*/
    return $db;
}
$db = mysqlconnect();
```