# Php simple login script white page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello im trying to implant PDO   into my login script to make it safrer from sql injection. But im getting a white page i think its because im trying to count the rows to see if the user is real.....

```
// Here we inculde the function page
include 'functions/functions.php';
// Here we connect to the db
$db = mysqlconnect();

$password = md5($_POST['mypassword']);
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$statement->execute(array($_POST['myusername'], $password));


// Replace counting function based on database you are using.
 $count = $statement->rowCount();
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count == 1){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername ;


//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}


$updateinfo=mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET lastip ='$ip' WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_log 
(username, ip) VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."', '$ip' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());  





header("Location: home.php");
} else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}


echo"<p> </p>";
```

Im not getting any error's just a white page.

Also here is my function page which i include

```
    function mysqlconnect(){
     global $db;
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = 3306; // This is the default port for MySQL
    $database = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    // Construct the DSN, or "Data Source Name".  Really, it's just a fancy name
    // for a string that says what type of server we're connecting to, and how
    // to connect to it.  As long as the above is filled out, this line is all
    // you need :)
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";

    // Connect!
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

}
```

Comment: Stop using the `global` keyword. And what are you using `md5()` for? And are you sure you have enabled error reporting.

Comment: yes error error reporting is on. And return $db;  shows has no db selected ( when int he function file there is ) And i use md5 because the users passwords is md5...

Comment: You're still using `mysql_query`. What are you trying to accomplish? I see you're using PDO to connect to the db, but then your using `mysql_query` outside of that

Comment: I suggest you to read up on the topic: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Another read would be http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and I think just going through http://php.net/manual/en/ wouldn't hurt

Comment: Ok ive toke the mysql update out and still a white page ive even turned error reporting on at the top of the page in side the script error_reporting(E_ALL); but just a white page...

Answer (score 1):

There's couple of things in your code that sticks in the eyeball.

If you pasted the whole script here, you're missing `session_start()`. I don't know what's in your `home.php`, but if it's content generation depends on a value in $_SESSION['username'], it's never going to happen because it will be empty after the header redirection.

Take a look at the manual about [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Also, as stated:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

Just in case thought to mention this. I've spent some good amount of time in the past wondering this thing myself.

You might want to take a glance at example #2 on the manual about [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

And of course, as @Paul already pointed, you shouldn't be using `mysql_query()` anymore if migrating to PDO.

Comment: the server has session_start all ready i put it onto the page then get 100s of error's saying headers all ready sent...

Comment: If you get nagging about headers already sent, it happens on this line: `header("Location: home.php");` You must have some outputting to browser somewhere before that line.